# Combine log lines with awk

Tags: parsing, logging, awk

I have a log file that simplified looks like this (it has enough columns so that direct addressing of the columns is not feasible):

```
id,time,host,ip,user_uuid
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.001Z,,,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.002Z,foo_host,,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.003Z,,192.168.0.1,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.004Z,,,foo_user
bar1,2022-05-10T00:02.005Z,,,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:03.006Z,bar_host,,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:04.007Z,,192.168.0.13,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:05.008Z,,,bar_user
```

Most of the fields appear only once by `id` but not all of them (see time, for example).

What I want to achieve is to have one line per `id` that combines the columns of all records with the same `id`:

```
id,time,host,ip,user_uuid
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.001Z,foo_host,192.168.0.1,foo_user
bar1,2022-05-10T00:03.006Z,bar_host,192.168.0.13,bar_user
```

For the columns that appear more than once in each `id`, I don't care which one is returned as long as it relates to a record with the same `id`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output **and your attempt to solve the problem yourself** so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would exploit GNU `AWK` 2D arrays following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
id,time,host,ip,user_uuid
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.001Z,,,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.002Z,foo_host,,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.003Z,,192.168.0.1,
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.004Z,,,foo_user
bar1,2022-05-10T00:02.005Z,,,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:03.006Z,bar_host,,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:04.007Z,,192.168.0.13,
bar1,2022-05-10T00:05.008Z,,,bar_user
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";cols=5}NR==1{print}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=cols;i+=1){arr[$1][i]=arr[$1][i]?arr[$1][i]:$i}}END{for(i in arr){for(j in arr[i]){$j=arr[i][j]};print}}' file.txt
```

output

```
id,time,host,ip,user_uuid
bar1,2022-05-10T00:02.005Z,bar_host,192.168.0.13,bar_user
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.001Z,foo_host,192.168.0.1,foo_user
```

Explanation: Firstly I inform GNU `AWK` that both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) is `,`, I use `cols` variable for holding information how many columns you wish to have. First row I simply `print`, for following rows for each column I check if there is already some truthy value in arr[id][number of field] using so-called ternary operator if yes I use it otherwise I set value to current field. In `END` I use nested for loops, for each id I do set value of its field in current line, so GNU `AWK` build string from these which I can `print`. Disclaimer: this solution assumes number of columns is equal in all lines and number of columns is known a priori and any order of output is acceptable. If this does not hold then develop own superior solution.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ruby` csv parser to group then reduce the repeated entries:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
data=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:col_sep=>","})
puts data[0].to_csv
data[1..].group_by { |row| row[0] }.
each{ |k, arr| 
   puts arr.transpose().map{ |ta| ta.find { |x| !x.nil? }}.to_csv
}   
' file
```

Prints:

```
id,time,host,ip,user_uuid
foo1,2022-05-10T00:01.001Z,foo_host,192.168.0.1,foo_user
bar1,2022-05-10T00:02.005Z,bar_host,192.168.0.13,bar_user
```

This assumes the valid data is the first non-nil, nonblank encountered for that particular column.